# Wrong SQL statement in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the value `SESSIONID` from this table:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONSLOG(
  SESSIONID VARCHAR2(30 ) NOT NULL,
  USERNAME VARCHAR2(30 ),
  IPADDRESS VARCHAR2(30 ),
  LOGINTIME TIMESTAMP(6),
  LOGOUTTIME TIMESTAMP(6)
)
/
```

I tried this SQL query:

```
SELECT SESSIONID FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG
```

But I get this error message:

```
ORA-00904: "SESSIONID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 7
```

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're querying the wrong table:

```
CREATE TABLE SESSIONSLOG
```

...

```
SELECT SESSIONID FROM ACTIVESESSIONSLOG
```

`ACTIVESESSIONSLOG` is not the same as `SESSIONSLOG`.

Answer (score 2):

You are querying wrong table ... table should be `SESSIONSLOG`

```
SELECT SESSIONID FROM SESSIONSLOG
```

Answer (score 1):

@user1285928 you are not supposed to use " ACTIVESESSIONSLOG " .

Instead Use SESSIONSLOG. Also use the delimiter symbol ;

SELECT SESSIONID FROM SESSIONSLOG;